# Python: What does .format(name, age) do in this wrapper-called suite?

Tags: python, logging, format, wrapper

I have two questions. Please explain like I'm 5.

1. What is the function of **format(name, age)** in print('display_info ran with arguments ({}, {})'.format(name, age)) ? Similarly, there is also **format(orig_func.**name**)**. What is that for?
2. What does logging.INFO do?

```
def my_logger(orig_func):
    import logging
    logging.basicConfig(filename='{}.log'.format(orig_func.__name__), level=logging.INFO)

    def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        logging.info(
            'Ran with args: {}, and kwargs: {}'.format(args, kwargs))
        return orig_func(*args, **kwargs)

    return wrapper

@my_logger
def display_info(name, age):
    time.sleep(1)
    print('display_info ran with arguments ({}, {})'.format(name, age))

display_info('John', 25)
```

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html#string.Formatter

Comment: Any Python tutorial should explain string formatting. It's a really common operation, it's hard to imagine how you haven't encountered it before.